# Java: Obtener la moda de una Lista de objetos

Tags: java, lista, frecuencia

La idea es que de cualquier lista `Object` en java, se pueda obtener la moda de los elementos. Esto quiere decir TODOS los elementos que tengan la misma y máxima frecuencia.

El ejemplo es la siguiente lista:

```java
ArrayList<Object> strings = new ArrayList<>(
        Arrays.asList("hello", "world", "my",
                "world", "is", "you", "and",
                "your", "world", "is", "me",
                "is", "love", "this", "?")
);
```

Donde vemos que se repiten 3 veces las palabras: "*hello*" e "*is*"

El resultado debería ser algo similar a:

| Objeto | frecuencia |
| --- | --- |
| "hello" | 3 |
| "is" | 3 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Observaciones

- La respuesta esperada tiene la estructura de un *map*, pues el objeto actúa como llave y la frecuencia como valor.
- La comparación puede suceder entre cualquier objeto, es decir String, Boolean, Integer, etc. Por lo cual debemos de tener cuidado al momento de contar las frecuencias, pues no podemos usar métodos como `String.equalsIgnoreCase` o `Integer.compare`, si no, debemos usar métodos propios de la clase [Object](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html), es decir, nos tendremos que limitar al uso del método [Object.equals](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object))

## Para revolver el problema

### Solución 1

1. Nos serán muy útiles los [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html)
2. Usaremos un [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html) como *map*
3. Crearemos un método que nos retorne el *HashMap* con las llaves y frecuencias máximas

```java
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Utils {

    /**
     * From an Object list returns a HashMap with the most repeated Objects
     * @param objects Object list
     * @return a HashMap with the Object and frequency
     */
    public HashMap<Object, Integer> getMaxFrequencies(ArrayList<Object> objects) {
        HashMap<Object, Integer> mode = new HashMap<>();
        objects.stream().distinct().forEach(e -> {
            mode.put(e, Collections.frequency(objects, e));
        });

        int max = Collections.max(mode.values());

        return (HashMap<Object, Integer>) mode.entrySet()
                .stream().filter(e -> e.getValue() == max)
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
    }
}
```

**Anotaciones**

1. De la lista creamos un [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) de los elementos distintos usando [Stream.distinct](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct()), de ahí por cada elemento contamos su frecuencia con [Collections.frequency](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#frequency(java.util.Collection,java.lang.Object)), de esta manera podemos hacer el *mapping* de la frecuencia con la aparece cada objeto
2. Con [Collections.max](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection)) hallamos la moda, para ello se usan los valores del mapa, los cuales pueden ser accedidos mediante [HashMap.values](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html#values())
3. Finalmente filtramos el mapa para que queden únicamente las relaciones cuyos valores sean igual a la moda. Se crea el *Stream* a partir del *Hashmap*, se filtran los valores y luego del stream se vuelve a crear el mapa.

### Solución 2

```java
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Utils {

    /**
     * From an Object list returns a HashMap with the most repeated Objects
     * @param objects Object list
     * @return a HashMap with the Object and frequency
     */
    public HashMap<Object, Integer> getMaxFrequencies2(ArrayList<Object> objects) {
        HashMap<Object, Integer> mode = new HashMap<>();

        int max = objects.stream().distinct()
                .mapToInt(e -> Collections.frequency(objects, e))
                .max().orElse(-1);

        objects.stream().distinct().forEach(e -> {
            if (Collections.frequency(objects, e) == max)
                mode.put(e, max);
        });

        return mode;
    }
}
```

**Anotaciones**

De manera contraria a la primera solución, aquí primero se encuentra la frecuencia máxima, haciendo el [Stream.mapToInt](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToInt(java.util.function.ToIntFunction)) de las frecuencias y seleccionando el máximo. Después de ello se agregan al *HashMap* aquellos Objectos cuya frecuencia coincida con el máximo.

Personalmente prefiero la solución 2 pues creo que es más eficiente (a simple vista, pues no se tiene que filtrar y volver a crear un mapa), aunque ambas soluciones me parecen totalmente válidas